# Resizing image size and text position with browser window in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am developing a webpage for Siemens PLC, for displaying where on production line is a potential "traffic jam". My plan is to insert a .jpg image of production line into the  webpage and then place red circles onto each machine of a production line. Then I would change color with javascript and jquery.

I already figured it out, how to change color of css circles with jquery and javascript, according to the PLC variables. The main problem is, I want my image of a production line, to resize with browser window like in this example:

[jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j884de0d/1/)

```
 html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    img {
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

So now my question is, how to position my circle indicators on the image, so the indicator would keep its position on the picture even when the browser window is resized?

Comment: I suggest you use a canvas instead. Alternatively place the circles at the server, then the image will resize accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should better to use svg image or canvas for  this achievement. You can use Javascript to position elements easily.